# How to align text in justify with jspdf in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, jspdf

I am using jspdf to create a pdf with nodejs, but I have a problem when displaying text data. I would like to align the text justified, I only found a plugin to align text in left center and right but nothing Justified, can anybody help me?

Sorry for my english

Comment: the solution was not to use jspdf, since unfortunately it does not support that functionality, currently use pdf make, sorry for my English